# Submitting with the ENTER on a form that has radio buttons

Tags: submit, keypress

I've got a form that contains only radio buttons. I expect the user the be able to select a radio button, then press enter to submit the form. But ENTER does not trigger form submit and I find no way to capture a keypress on a radio button. It seems to just not fire.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to write some javascript to route the enter key to the form submit.  This method has been discussed here:

[How to submit a form when the return key is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943/how-to-submit-a-form-when-the-return-key-is-pressed)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/tWQLt/2/) seems to work

```
$("input").on("keydown", function(ev) {
    if (ev.keyCode == 13)
        alert('submit here!');
}).on("click", function(ev) {
    $(this).focus();
});
```

Tested in FireFox, IE and Chrome.