# Submit form on Enter key with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, key, submit, enter

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. I want the enter key to work as well as clicking the button.

```
<form action="" method="get" class="priceOptionForm" name="priceOptionForm">
   <input name="paypal_email" type="text" value="whatever" id="email" />
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="bluebtn" id="profile_price" style="width:60px;margin-top:5px;">Save all</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Which one doesn't work? The enter key, or the button?

Comment: I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943/how-to-submit-a-form-when-the-return-key-is-pressed

Answer (score 38):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('email').onkeydown = function(e){
   if(e.keyCode == 13){
     // submit
   }
};
```

Answer (score 18):

Please use below code snippet...It should be added into script block

```
<script>
    document.onkeydown=function(evt){
        var keyCode = evt ? (evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode) : event.keyCode;
        if(keyCode == 13)
        {
            //your function call here
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 10):

All below codes should be added into script block or file.
define submit function:

```
function submitForm(){
    document.priceOptionForm.submit();
    document.priceOptionForm.method='post';
}
```

For the enter key to submit form:

```
document.onkeydown=function(){
    if(window.event.keyCode=='13'){
        submitForm();
    }
}
```

For the link to work:

```
document.getElementById("profile_price").onclick=submitForm;
```

You can refer to http://jsfiddle.net/honglonglong/YMX2q/ for some trying.

Answer (score 9):

Use an `<input type="submit">` instead of a link. Then the enter key will work automatically.

Comment: Nice, but beware if you have some kind of javascript validation attached to the "onSubmit" of your form.

Answer (score 5):

simply make a hidden button like this 
HTML

```
<input type="submit" id="submitbtn"  />
```

CSS

```
#submitbtn{display:none;}
```

when the user will hit the enter button the form will be submitted

Don't forget to put the type="submit"

Comment: <input type="submit" style="display: none;" />

Answer (score 1):

```
// Process form if use enter key. put script in head.    
document.onkeyup = enter;    
function enter(e) {if (e.which == 13) submitForm();}

// uses keyup not down as better practice imo    
// submitForm() is user function that posts the form
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can Put a Default Button ID  in form tag is automatically trigger

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="Button1">

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"

    OnClick = "Button1_Click" />

<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button"

    OnClick = "Button2_Click" />

<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button"

    OnClick = "Button3_Click" />

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

</form>
```

Comment: if you want to do code behind refer below
    
        this.Form.DefaultButton = "Button1";

Answer (score 0):

Oh that is because the HTML form element does not recognize the link as a button, to click..
you need to replace it with a button...

```
<input type="submit" value="this will display on your button" onClick="javascript:void(0)">
```

but if you want it to look like a link you should do this in the css

```
<style type="text/css">
input{background-color:white;border:0 none;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The submit event fires when the user clicks a submit button (`<button>` or `<input type="submit">`) or **presses Enter** while editing a field (e.g. `<input type="text">`) in a form. The event is not sent to the form when calling the `form.submit()` method directly.
[check documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onKeyDown` in `input` tag.

Below is the details of it.

```
const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
   if(e.key === "Enter") {
        //form actions
   }
}

<form action="" method="get" class="priceOptionForm" name="priceOptionForm">
   <input name="paypal_email" type="text" value="whatever" id="email" onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} />
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="bluebtn" id="profile_price" style="width:60px;margin-top:5px;">Save all</a>
</form>
```