# Submit form with enter via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to submit the text within the input field by pressing the enter key,and then put the form text into a list item. Problem is,when I press enter it just refreshes the page and nothing happens,and I cna't use anything back-end ,this is purely front-end... this is a to-do list by the way,and this is what I've done so far:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Site</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="text">
                 <h1>To-Do</h1><br>
            </div>
            <form>
                <input type="text" id='uzd' placeholder="Ką reikia atlikti?">
                <button type="submit" form="uzd" value="Submit" hidden onsubmit="button()"></button>
            </form>
            <ul id='uzduotys'>

            </ul>
            <script src="script.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>





function button(){
    var node = document.createElement("Li");
    node.setAttribute("class","li-item");
    var text = document.getElementById("uzd").value;
    if(text===""){
        alert("placeholder");
    }
    else{
        var textnode =document.createTextNode(text);
        node.appendChild(textnode);
        document.getElementById("uzduotys").appendChild(node);
    }




}

var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
        ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit form on Enter key with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484738/submit-form-on-enter-key-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You were almost right: you need to move the onsubmit field to the form element, and add "return false;" to the value of onsubmit, to prevent the form to be really submitted. Then you can also remove the button element which becomes useless. See working code below:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Site</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text">
      <h1>To-Do</h1><br>
    </div>
    <form onsubmit="button(); return false;">
      <input type="text" id='uzd' placeholder="Ką reikia atlikti?">
    </form>
    <ul id='uzduotys'>

    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<script language="javascript">
  function button() {
    var node = document.createElement("Li");
    node.setAttribute("class", "li-item");
    var text = document.getElementById("uzd").value;
    if (text === "") {
      alert("placeholder");
    } else {
      var textnode = document.createTextNode(text);
      node.appendChild(textnode);
      document.getElementById("uzduotys").appendChild(node);
    }
  }

  var list = document.querySelector('ul');
  list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
      ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
    }
  }, false);
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: It works! though, upon submitting it seems like the site is just stacking the list elements on top of eachother,any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I see each new item appearing at the bottom of the previous one, which is the expected behavior for a todo list...

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the fact that a form is submitted with Enter by default. However, you'll want to replace the default submit behavior (which is to, well, submit data), with your function using `onsubmit`, and prevent the default behavior with a `return false;`:

```
<form onsubmit="handleSubmitSomehow(event); return false">
    <input type="text" id='uzd' placeholder="Ką reikia atlikti?">
    <button type="submit" value="Submit"></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

- Pass the event and get the keycode from it.
- If it is `enter` key then add the entered value as a list item.

```js
function validate(e, thisObj) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();  
        //console.log(thisObj.value);  
        
        var ul = document.getElementById("uzduotys");
        
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        
        li.innerHTML = thisObj.value;
        
        ul.appendChild(li);
        
        
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Site</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="text">
    <h1>To-Do</h1><br>
    </div>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id='uzd' placeholder="Ką reikia atlikti?" onkeypress="return validate(event, this)">
    </form>
    <ul id='uzduotys'>

    </ul>
  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not submitting the form to some back-end, I would just not use a form at all and instead use a keyup listener for the enter key on the input element.

Don't fix a problem like preventing a form submit if you can avoid the problem in the first place.