# Form with two inputs not submitting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Could someone please explain why this code isn't working:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var first = $('.first').val();
    var next = $(".next").val();
    alert(first + " " + next);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cj1hysf3/

It seems to work fine when I remove one of the two inputs but having them both there messes it up.

Comment: The default action of a submit event is to submit the form, when you call `e.preventDefault()` you are removing that functionality :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cj1hysf3/1/ ?

Comment: I think OP just want the alert to come... not to do a real form submit but to trigger the handler

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need a submit button. You can hide it if you want but for enter to submit a form by default, it needs to be there.

```js
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var first = $('.first').val();
    var next = $(".next").val();
    alert(first + " " + next);
});
```

```css
input[type="submit"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="a" class="first" placeholder="Enter First" />
    <input type="text" name="s" class="next" placeholder="Enter Next" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

[From the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#implicit-submission):

> “If the form has no submit button, then the implicit submission mechanism must do nothing if the form has more than one *field that blocks implicit submission*, and must submit the form element from the form element itself otherwise.”
>
> “For the purpose of the previous paragraph, an element is a *field that blocks implicit submission* of a form element if it is an input element whose form owner is that form element and whose type attribute is in one of the following states: Text, […]”

Answer (score 6):

This behavior is explicitly specified in HTML5.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#implicit-submission:

> “If the form has no submit button, then the implicit submission mechanism must do nothing if the form has more than one *field that blocks implicit submission*, and must submit the form element from the form element itself otherwise.”
>
> “For the purpose of the previous paragraph, an element is a *field that blocks implicit submission* of a form element if it is an input element whose form owner is that form element and whose type attribute is in one of the following states: Text, […]”

Both of your input fields are of `type=text`, so the browser is *not allowed* to implicitly submit the form when you press enter inside on the fields.

You could add a `keydown` handler that checks which key was pressed, and calls the `submit` method of the form or your function explicitly when that key happens to be the `[enter]` key. (Details about that should be easy enough to find through search.)

Answer (score 1):

Clarification: I think you're asking why the `enter` key doesn't submit the form when there are two `input` elements, but it does submit the form when there is only one `input` element.

I believe it's due to the nature of forms (and maybe just the way that browsers work). When submitting a single form input you can be sure that there is no more values to comes so an enter key will submit the form. If there's more than one input, then perhaps the browser doesn't submit the form on the `enter` key as there's potentially another form you're not done with. Generally, you'll want a submit button on most of your forms anyway, if not, you could do as suggested in this answer: [How to submit a form when the return key is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943/how-to-submit-a-form-when-the-return-key-is-pressed#answer-29951)