# HTML form onsubmit fails to fire on certain browsers with hidden submit button and readonly input

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm designing a form to trigger `onsubmit` upon pressing "Enter" on the keyboard, and the event isn't firing on certain browsers depending on what fields are in the form.

Here are some minimal working examples of forms that trigger and don't trigger `submit`.

Firefox, Chrome, and Opera are happy with the following forms, but Internet Explorer 11 and Safari 11 won't trigger `onsubmit` on the third form.

Form 1:

```
<form>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit" style="display:none;">
</form>
```

Form 2:

```
<form>
    <input type="text">
    <input readonly>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Form 3 (bugged):

```
<form>
    <input type="text">
    <input readonly>
    <input type="submit" style="display:none;">
</form>
```

How can I get the third form to trigger `submit` on those browsers when pressing 'Enter' while keeping the submit button hidden and not using a hacky keypress event handler? An explanation for why the third form fails to trigger the event would be super helpful.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/4pdavu0t/) is a JSFiddle for your convenience.

Edit: The related question's accepted solution sets `display: none` on the submit button, which would not have resolved this issue in Safari/IE.

Comment: _"An explanation for why the third form fails to trigger the event would be super helpful."_ - because it has no submit button (as @Dummy said, with `display:none` it's as if it wasn't there at all), _and_ more than one field that blocks implicit submission (the two text fields) - this is specified behavior in HTML5, see my answer to a previous question of similar nature here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28709364/1427878

Comment: The focus of the other question was text input fields, so I only quoted “and whose type attribute is in one of the following states: Text, […]” from the specification, but that list goes on, “Search, URL, Telephone, E-mail, Password, Date, Time, Number” - so if you need to _send_ that `readonly` value with the other form data (right now still a `text` field, because that's default if `type` is omitted,) then I'd suggest you replace it with a `hidden` input (takes care of sending the value, and doesn't block implicit submission), and add the same value for the user to see in a `span` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none` because `display: none` elements do not receive events

Or use opacity and absolutely position it offscreen so it does not take up any space and does not appear on the screen

```
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
left: -3000px;
```

Comment: Why did the first form trigger `submit`, then?

Comment: @user9027325 because it had only one field that blocks implicit submission - see my comment, and the answer I'm referring to for more details.

Comment: I suppose that solution works, even if it's not the most elegant.

Comment: That's what you do if you want to support multiple browsers