# How to send ENTER key in protractor tests on iOS?

Tags: ios, protractor, appium

I'm using ProtractorJS (and Appium) to test a website on browsers and devices. One of the tests is to type some text in the search box and then hit ENTER. Here is the snippet from the page object.

```
page.searchInput.sendKeys("Text");
page.searchInput.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
```

The above two lines work fine on any browser and Android devices. However, the same test fails on iOS because the ENTER key is not sent. In the iOS keyboard the key I have to press is the "Search" one.

The test must trigger the search using the keyboard.

Any ideas on how to send the ENTER key on iOS?

Comment: Did you try to send `\n` instead? Here's how - `page.searchInput.sendKeys("Text\n");`.

Comment: Thanks for the response @GirishSortur. I've just tried and it didn't work

Comment: Ok, how about `page.searchInput.sendKeys(protractor.Key.RETURN);` or `self.driver.execute_script('UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().keyboard().buttons()["Search"].tap();');` ? Seems like return should be pressed instead of enter.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I tried with `RETURN` and didn't work. I've tried the other option `browser.executeScript('UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().keyboard().b‌​uttons()["Search"].tap();');` and I got `- UnknownError: Invalid character '\u8203'`

Comment: try this: `UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().keyboard().buttons().firstWi‌​thPredicate("name contains[c] 'search'");`
or:
`UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().keyboard().b‌​utt‌​ons()["search"].tap();` - note the lowercase

Comment: Same thing `Invalid character '\u8203'`. When the text is typed in the search box, the keyboard does not open so I'm wondering if for the script to run properly the keyboard has to be open. If so, no idea how to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

If there is no button on the page, Safari will be stubborn about it and not submit the form. In general, I use the button tag instead of the input tag and have better results, but either way unless there is a submit button on the page, and that button is visible (see this question for reference: [How to submit a form when the return key is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943/how-to-submit-a-form-when-the-return-key-is-pressed)), Safari will stubbornly refuse to submit the page. In this case, I would put a submit button on the page even though most users will never use it on mobile. You may have fits getting it past your design department. The other option is to use a blur event and trigger it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can send just new line symbol `\n` or create tap by coordinate proportions at the right lower corner of the app.