# How to replace <button> with enter key?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So basically I have a page where users can post a status, users are able to comment on these status's by typing in the textbox and clicking on the 'Reply' button. However I much rather remove the button so users can just press the enter key to post a reply. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<div id="status_'.$statusid.'" class="panel panel-default">

<form>
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" id="replytext_'.$statusid.'" onkeyup="statusMax(this,250)" class="form-control" placeholder="Add a comment.." autocomplete="off">
</div>

<button id="replyBtn_'.$statusid.'" onclick="replyToStatus('.$statusid.',\''.$url.'\',\'replytext_'.$statusid.'\',this)">Reply</button>
</form>

</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to submit a form when the return key is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943/how-to-submit-a-form-when-the-return-key-is-pressed)

Comment: Move the button outside of the window with the css position property and it should be triggered when the enter key is pressed.  Make sure the button is wrapped by a form element.

Answer (score 1):

You can submit a form by pressing enter when a form element is active. See the following snippet that just hooks into the form via it's onSubmit event handler.

```js
function handleSubmit() {
  alert('Do your thing...');
}
```

```html
<form id="commentForm" onSubmit="handleSubmit(); return false;">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="replytext_" class="form-control" placeholder="Add a comment.." autocomplete="off">
  </div>
</form>
```